# Play music in iPhone using iTunes

Tags: itunes, iphone

Is there a way to play music on an iPhone which is connected to a DVD player using iTunes on my PC?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you have connected you iPhone's output to a DVD player for amplification. You can stream your iTunes content to iPhone using Home Sharing (see [this ArsTechnica guide](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2011/03/how-to-set-up-itunes-home-sharing-to-stream-to-your-ios-device.ars)) or AirPlay (using [AirView](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/01/airview-turns-iphone-ipad-into-airplay-receiver/) on the iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

Your wording was a bit ambiguous, but I believe you are trying to use iTunes to play music which is on your iPhone. If that's correct:

Assuming you have the latest versions of iOS and iTunes installed, plug in your iPhone (this is a one-time setup by the way), wait for iTunes to do all the normal mounting and stuff, and then rather than eject it, simply unplug it. As long as the iPhone is connected to the same network as the computer, just browse the iPhone's library from iTunes and play away!

If the iPhone is not yours, be sure to un-tick any automatic syncing options in iTunes before anything else.

Comment: When i do this (Timothy), the songs show up grey and i can't even select the songs. The only thing i can do is right click and see the context menu with: Get Info; and Show in Playlist-> Is there something relating to permissions i need to setup on my iPhone? The computer I'm using has Home Sharing enabled with the account that the iPhone uses anyway - so it doesn't seem like that would be the solution. BTW i dont know if this matters but it shows up as a device not as a shared library.